# Hermitian matrix and theorem about its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a theorem says that:

> Let $A = [a_{ij}] \in M_n$ be Hermitian. If $a_{ii} = \lambda_{1}$,
>   then $a_{ik} = a_{ki} = 0$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots, n , k\neq i.$ The eigenvalues are ordered as $\lambda_{1} \leq \lambda_{2} \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_{n}$.

I would like to prove, and this is trivial for the $n= 2$. However I need some hint to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is actually a special case of Rayleigh's principle, which says that for any self-adjoint matrix $A$, its minimum eigenvalue is given by $\min_{\|x\|=1}x^\ast Ax$ and if $v=\arg\min_{\|x\|=1}x^\ast Ax$, then $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.

Suppose $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_k<\lambda_{k+1}\le\cdots\le\lambda_n$. Let $A=U^\ast\Lambda U$ be a unitary diagonalisation, where $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. Let also $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)^\top$ be the $i$-th column of $U$. Then one can show that $u^\ast\Lambda u=a_{ii}=\lambda_1$. Hence $u_{k+1}=\cdots=u_n=0$, $u$ is an eigenvector of $\Lambda$. In turn, $e_i$, the $i$-th vector in the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$, is an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: @Amin Sorry, it should be Rayleigh's principle rather than Courant-Fischer minimax principle. Rayleigh's principle concerns about the max. and min. eigenvalues of  $A$ as well as their extremisers, but the minimax principle only deal with the eigenvalues. As for your other question, recall that the other $\lambda$s are strictly greater than $\lambda_1$.

Comment: @Amin That's what happens if $Ae_i=\lambda_1e_i$.

Comment: I had a confusion and it is totally solved. Thanks @user1551.

Comment: I have two questions @user1551: 1. Your last sentence is true with just the assumptions $a_{ii}= \lambda_{1}$ and $A$ is Hermitian; isn't it true? I mean we can directly deduce the result since $e_{i}$ is the eigenvector? 2. Can we say this statement is true for any $\lambda$ such that $a_{ii} = \lambda$?

Comment: @Amin (1) Yes. (2) No, we cannot deduce that $u$ is an eigenvector of $\Lambda$ if we are merely told that $a_{ii}$ is equal to *some* eigenvalue of $A$. The current argument works only if $a_{ii}$ is equal to the minimum or the maximum eigenvalue. It doesn't work with the intermediate ones.